# Populating a dropdown menu with data from sql server database in vb2008 at runtime

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-binding

I am developing an application in visual basic 2008. I want to populate a drop down list onthe fly with values extracted from the database. I want both the displayed and value items to come from the same.

Any help with be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out [displaymember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx), [valuemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) and [datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for listbox and combobox.